# Maxfilesexceeded triggers error

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm having an issue when triggering `maxfilesexceeded` event, it triggers the `error` event. I'm handling it this way

```
this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                        this.removeAllFiles();
                        this.addFile(file);
                    });
```

But it keeps triggering the error event, which I'm only using for displaying an error response from the server (there's no sense in the message keep being displayed over and over when the files are removed), is there a way to tell the `maxfilesexceeded` to not trigger the code in `error`?

Answer (score 1):

problem is with your syntax inner (this) keyword belongs to maxfilesexceeded event thats why you getting error.Use below code to override maxfilesexceeded event:

```
   init:function() {       
        var myDropzone = this;    
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                 myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                 myDropzone.addFile(file);
        });
    }
```